Is GNU Octave multi-threaded?
Based on the answers to this old questions, it seems GNU Octave is a single-thread application.
However, I am experimenting with an old Octave neural network package called nnet and was surprised that my Octave programs use all 4 cores of my laptop. Have things changes since the question I have linked was made and is GNU Octave now multi-threaded? As far as I can tell, I don't see any parallel implementation inside nnet.
Some info on my installation:

My OS is Linux Mint 20
My machine has 4 processing units (this is what nproc displays in my terminal)
My Octave version is 5.2.0 (I am using the GUI if that makes a difference)

My code is rather simple and only import the nnet package, nothing else. When I look at the resources when I run my program, I see all cores are used (below is the htop screenshot)

Here is what I am doing:
pkg load nnet

starttime = clock();

# taken from http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/toolbox/nnet/newff.html
Pr = -1:0.00005:1;
Tr = 3*sin(pi*Pr)-cos(pi*Pr);
Prmin = min(Pr);
Prmax = max(Pr);
net = newff([Prmin Prmax],[3 2 1],{'tansig','logsig','purelin'},'trainlm');
[net] = train(net,Pr,Tr,[],[],[]);
[netoutput] = sim(net,Pr);

etime(clock(),starttime)

% the test results 
plot(Pr,Tr,'b+');
hold on; 
plot(Pr,netoutput,'r-');
hold off;

EDIT
Following @JérômeRichard hint and @NickJ suggestions in the comments, I started Octave allocating only 1 thread to BLAS by doing export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 in the terminal. The script is twice as fast as it was with the original settings (which by default was 4 according to the htop screenshot posted above). I made sure my program was using only one core with htop.

Octave is single-threaded but some library can use multiple thread (native ones). The same thing applies for other interpreted languages like Python or R.

Thank for clarifying @JérômeRichard. I have actually ported Octave's nnet to R and started to compare the performance. Regardless of other things, what stood out the most to me was the use of multiple threads in Octave compared to the use of a single thread in R. I will deep dive into how I can go about multi-threading in R, now that I know that (some) Octave's libraries use multithread.

I guess part of the answer is that GNU Octave uses OpenBLAS which is multi-threaded (at least the Linux Mint version I have). Can you confirm this? In any case, thanks again, and should you wish to turn your comment to answer I would be happy to accept it.

Yes, OpenBLAS is multi-threaded. You can control the number of threads using OpenMP env variables : OMP_NUM_THREADS (if you set it to 1, you should see a serial execution).

it would be interesting to switch the BLAS library used by octave to verify this switch makes the difference (and how much)

yep, I am investigating on this topic, hopefully I will figure things out. However, compared to what I stated above, R does use multiple threads (and uses BLAS). The main difference with Octave in my use case is that Octave seems to use all my 4 cores at full (100%), whereas R uses one at 100% and the rest around 70-80%. For R I see that I can use the RhpcBLASctl package to set the number of thread BLAS uses. Surprisingly, using 1 thread is twice as fast as using 4 (maybe due to the overhead of multi-threading? Who knows...)

@JérômeRichard @NickJ I did a test and setting OMP_NUM_THREADS to 1 is twice as fast compared to the default value (which in my case should be 4). I opened htop to make sure I was using only 1 core, and, as it happens with R, allocating only 1 thread to BLAS seems to improve the performance of my script. Interesting, thanks for the good hint! I will edit my answer to reflect this.
